# Django problem, Exception Value: Friend matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django

I'm doing a `Django` blog website project.

One of my features is when you log in, you can click on the tab `Other members` to show you a list of other members; like this picture

[image: like in this picture].

However, as of now, this feature only works when I login as one specific account which is an admin. When I log in as other members (not the admin) or another admin account, the feature is not working; that means when I click the tab `Other Members` it will display errors like

```
"Friend matching query does not exist"
```

[image: Friend matching query does not exist.]

I'm really confused and getting stuck on this one. Any ideas how to solve it?

Here is my code:

**list_users.html **

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h2>Other People</h2>
        {% for user in users %}
            <a href="{% url 'view_profile_with_pk' pk=user.pk %}">
                <h3>{{ user.username }}</h3>
            </a>
            {% if not user in friends %}
            <a href="{% url 'change_friends' operation='add' pk=user.pk %}">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add Friend</button>
            </a>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h2>Friends</h2>
        {% for friend in friends %}
            <a href="{% url 'view_profile_with_pk' pk=friend.pk %}">
                <h3>{{ friend.username }}</h3>
            </a>
            <a href="{% url 'change_friends' operation='remove' pk=friend.pk %}">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Remove Friend</button>
            </a>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**views.py** function `listusers`

```
def listusers(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by()
    users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)
    friend = Friend.objects.get(current_user=request.user)
    friends = friend.users.all()

    context = {
        'posts': posts, 'users': users, 'friends': friends
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/list_users.html', context)
```

**model.py** class `Friend`

```
class Friend(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    current_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owner', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Can see your friend model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using `get` operator to get the friend. The problem as the image you provided shows, is in line 25 of your views. in below method:

```
friend = Friend.objects.get(current_user=request.user)
```

you are trying to get an item which does not exist. There is no friend that it's current_user is the requested user.

you can fix it like this:

```
friend = Friend.objects.filter(current_user=request.user).first()
if friend:
    friends = friend.users.all()
else: 
    friends = User.objects.none()
```

Comment: I suggest adding the method call `.first()` to `Friend.objects.filter(current_user=request.user)` for it to work properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I fix it like your answer but it gives me another error AttributeError at /listusers/
'UserManager' object has no attribute 'NONE'

Comment: it should be `User.objects.none()`

Comment: sorry it was a mistypo

Comment: Thank you it works now. 
Thanks everyone for helping me solve this problem, I really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `filter` instead of `get` . `get` throws exception when there's no matching result.

Have a look at [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)

```
Friend.objects.filter(current_user=request.user).first()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After changing friend = Friend.objects.get(current_user=request.user) to friend = Friend.objects.filter(current_user=request.user).first() like your answer, it gives me another error: AttributeError at /listusers/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'users'

Comment: You must check if friend is **not** `None` before accessing friends.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to create a Friend instance if a user does not have one. You can use [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) for this. For example:

```
users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)
friend, created = Friend.objects.get_or_create(current_user=request.user)  # or have other necessary fields for Friend field
friends = friend.users.all()

context = {
    'posts': posts, 'users': users, 'friends': friends
}
return render(request, 'blog/list_users.html', context)
```